# How to convert a Java Bean with sub-items to RDD[Row]

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a RDD which is composed of some Java beans. Every bean has a hashset containing some sub-items, like one order consisting of some items. I want to convert this Rdd[Order] to RDD[Row] and insert order and items into Order table and Item table inside Hive. Following is my code:

```
val orders = new ListBuffer[Order]()
val order = new Order(...)
order.itemSet = scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty[Item]
val item1 = new Item(...)
val item2 = new Item(...)
order.itemSet.add(item1)
order.itemSet.add(item2)
orders.add(order)

val orderRDD = sc.parallize(orders.toSeq)
val orderRows = orderRDD.map(order => {
    Row(order_field1, order_field2, ...)
  })
//hiveContext.insert(orderRows)
val itemRows = orderRDD.map(order => {
      order.item.map(item => {
        Row(order_item_field1, order_item_field2,...)
      })
    })
```

The problem is that "orderRows" is RDD[Seq[itemRow]], but I want a RDD[itemRow]. Anybody knows how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: "order.item.map(item => {" should be "order.itemSet.map(item =>{". Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to write like this:

```
val itemRows = orderRDD.map(order => {
  order.itemSet.map(item => {
    Row(order_item_field1, order_item_field2,...)
  })
}).fold(Set.empty[Row])((set1, set2) => set1 ++= set2).toSeq

val itemRDD = sc.parallize(itemRows)
```